# C# Deserialize XML with multiple XML declarations

Tags: c#, xml, xml-deserialization

A third part supplier has given us XML that is not well formed. It has multiple XML declarations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><!DOCTYPE bob />
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE jim>

<elements>
...
</elements
```

My de-serializing code:

```
 var serializer = new XmlSerializer(response.GetType());

                reader = new XmlTextReader(stream) {XmlResolver = null};

                result = (IResponse) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

The problem I am having is the de-serializer complains about the the multiple XML declarations. Is there any way I can strip the declarations off so that the XML successfully de-serializes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could write a wrapper around a `XmlReader`, which filters out subsequent xml processing instructions and doctypes.

```
public class XmlFilteringReader : XmlReader
{
    private readonly XmlReader _source;
    private bool _gotXmlDeclaration = false;
    private bool _gotDoctype = false;

    public XmlFilteringReader(XmlReader source)
    {
        _source = source;
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        var ok = _source.Read();
        if (ok && _source.NodeType == XmlNodeType.ProcessingInstruction
                && _source.LocalName == "xml")
        {
            if (_gotXmlDeclaration) return Read(); // Recursive
            _gotXmlDeclaration = true;
        }
        else if (ok && _source.NodeType == XmlNodeType.DocumentType)
        {
            if (_gotDoctype) return Read(); // Recursive
            _gotDoctype = true;
        }
        return ok;
    }

    // Implementation of other methods and properties
    // by calling the same method or property on _source
}
```

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(response.GetType());
var reader = new XmlFilteringReader(new XmlTextReader(stream) {XmlResolver = null});
var result = (IResponse) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
```

The implementation could be simplified by using [`XmlWrappingReader`](https://mvpxml.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Library/Main/Source/Common/XmlWrappingReader.cs) from the [Mvp.Xml](https://mvpxml.codeplex.com/) library. There is also [a blog-post](http://www.tkachenko.com/blog/archives/000585.html) about this.